# Adding items to a nosql objects with minimum time complexity

Tags: javascript, typescript, performance, nosql

In a nosql database multiple items are stored with the category and subcategory in the format given below.

```
    Category: [
        {id: "c2", subCategories: [ {id: "s2", items: [ {id: i3}, {id: i4} ] } ] }
        {id: "c1", subCategories: [ {id: "s1", items: [ {id: i1}, {id: i2} ] } ] }
    ]
```

Problem is to add new items with optimised time complexity, we get the same structure to add new items and we have to find and update the subcategories with the new items.

Let's say we get this

```
    Category: [
        {id: "c2", subCategories: [ {id: "s2", items: [ {id: i5} ] } ] }
        {id: "c1", subCategories: [ {id: "s1", items: [ {id: i6}, {id: i7} ] } ] }
    ]
```

then the result should be

```
Category: [
        {id: "c2", subCategories: [ {id: "s2", items: [ {id: i3}, {id: i4}, {id: i5} ] } ] } ]
        {id: "c1", subCategories: [ {id: "s1", items: [ {id: i1}, {id: i2},{id: i6}, {id: i7} ] }]
    ],
```

currently the approach I can think of, is to iterate over the data with multiple categories and subcategories the time complexity goes to n3 and then after getting the item which is to be added we have to find out where we need to add that item it further increases, is there a way we could reduce this complexity ?

Comment: Is this a question about efficiently merging those two structures in JavaScript/TypeScript? Or in the nosql database itself? If the second, then you will need to specify what database you're using.

Comment: Is the tree only 3 levels deep (category, subcategory, item), or can there be more levels? Does the order of categories, subcategories, and items matter?

Comment: Only 3 level tree, I'm using typescript and couchbase DB